# rxjs/redux observable Actions dispatched in the wrong order when running multiple tests

Tags: javascript, jasmine, rxjs, karma-jasmine, redux-observable

I'm writing some tests for redux observable epics with jasmine. When running one of the tests "alone" (with `fit(...)`) the test passes, but when running it in combination with another test (with `it(...)`) it fails because the actions are dispatched in the wrong order. Any help appreciated!

There are a few epics so I'm not going to post them unless necessary.

This is (kind of) the test file:

```
const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(combinedEpics)
const mockStore = configureMockStore([epicMiddleware])

describe('my test', () => {
  let store

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore(...)
    jasmine.Ajax.install()
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    jasmine.Ajax.uninstall()
    epicMiddleware.replaceEpic(combinedEpics)
  })

  // test 1 passes
  it("test 1", () => {
    jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest("url-1").andReturn({
      status: 200,
      responseText: JSON.stringify({ ... })
    })

    store.dispatch(initializePage())

    expect(store.getActions()).toEqual([
      { type: INITIALIZE_PAGE },
      { type: MY_ACTION1 },
      { type: INITIALIZED_PAGE }
    ])
  })

  // test 2 passes with `fit` but not with `it` 
  it("test 2", () => {
    jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest("url-2").andReturn({
      status: 200,
      responseText: JSON.stringify({ ... })
    })

    store.dispatch(initializePage())

    expect(store.getActions()).toEqual([
      { type: INITIALIZE_PAGE },
      { type: MY_ACTION2 },
      { type: INITIALIZED_PAGE }
    ])
    /**
     * With `fit` the actions come in the order [INITIALIZE_PAGE, MY_ACTION2, INITIALIZED_PAGE]
     * With `it` the actions come in the order [INITIALIZE_PAGE, INITIALIZED_PAGE, MY_ACTION2]
     */
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it works if I create `epicMidleware` in `beforeEach` instead of using `epicMiddleware.replace(combinedEpics)`. Like so:

```
describe('my test', () => {
  let store
  let epicMiddleware
  let mockStore

  beforeEach(() => {
    epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(combinedEpics)
    mockStore = configureMockStore([epicMiddleware])
    store = mockStore(...)
    jasmine.Ajax.install()
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    jasmine.Ajax.uninstall()
  })

  ...
```